# Best Practice for dealing with app engine cold start problem

Tags: python, google-app-engine

After a period of inactivity the first request takes about 5 to 10 secs to come through.

Is there any best practice solutions to overcome this problem?

I'm using Python version of App Engine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Reduce the set of libraries you require in order to serve requests as much as you can.
- For expensive libraries that are only used in some places, put the import statement inside the function that uses them. This way, the library is only imported the first time it's needed.
- If your framework supports it, do just-in-time importing of handlers, so you don't have to import them all when your app starts up.
- Look forward to reserved instances / warmup requests, coming soon!

Comment: "put the import statement inside the function that uses them", wow..that's rough :).

Comment: "Look forward to reserved instances / warmup requests, coming soon!" a very good news!